# How I can use multiple hosts in AWX playbook?

Tags: ansible

I have workflow that create 2 virtual machines on GCP. When virtual instance created I store output with external ip to variable. In next playbook i want to use all of my ip addresses in host section. My code is:

```
---
- name: Download and install jenkins
  hosts: 
   - "{{ node_1_ip }}"
   - "{{ node_2_ip }}"
  tasks:
   - name: Install java
     yum:
       name: java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
     become: true
```

But when I run my playbook i have warning:

```
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: 35.228.80.9
```

35.228.80.9 is my node_2_ip. How can I apply my playbook to this 2 machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you haven't set up the host in [your inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html) you can figure out where your hosts are being pulled from with the following command:

```
ansible-config dump | grep HOST
```

In practice, you probably just need to create an `inventory` file with the following content:

```
[nodes]
node01 ansible_host=IP OF YOUR FIRST NODE HERE!!!
node02 ansible_host=35.228.80.9
```

Then specify the `-i` parameter to `ansible-playbook`:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory -k playbook.yml
```

Depending on your exact use cases it might be more scalable and maintainable to use [GCE Dynamic Inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_gce.html#gce-dynamic-inventory), although this does require a little bit of extra setup.